# How to add a relative reference to a global variable in __init__.py in parent package from patch.object()?

Tags: python, python-import, python-unittest.mock, relative-import

I have the file structure as follow:

In `/packageA/__init__.py`:

```
from my_mako_stuff import mako_lookup

...
def func_in_package():
    ...
    template = mako_lookup(...)
```

In `/packageA/mas.py`:

```
from . import func_in_package

...# do some stuff with `func_in_package`
```

In `/packageA/mas_test.py`:

```
from .mas import *

mocked_templatelookup = MagicMock(get_template=Mock())
with patch.object(.mas.parent, # this fails because the reference doesn't work
                  'mako_lookup',
                   new=mocked_templatelookup,
                   create=True):
  ...
```

How to properly reference the `mako_lookup` global variable defined in the packageA's `__init__.py` module, from the `mas_test.py` which itself is within that package?

EDITTING NOTES:
As requested, I run this code as is and get a SyntaxError as follow:

```
File "mas_test.py", line 57
    with patch.object(.mas.parent, # this fails because the reference doesn't work
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is .mas.parent?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D that's the pseudo code representing the package where this testing code resides in.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, NameError. It's pseudo code afterall, not totally unexpected.

Comment: Add the traceback to the question, please. Does the solution by chepner works?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D traceback added. The solution suggested by chepner works, but it isn't the question that I intended. I was wondering if a relative reference here is possible. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Just patch the name `packageA.mako_lookup`, since that is what `func_in_package` uses.

```
with patch('packageA.mako_lookup', new=mocked_templatelookup, create=True):
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, but how to use relative path?

Comment: I wouldn't bother.